# .click() is not working with a tag and href

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create an event handler. I want to click the div tag and the a tag is also clicked, which should redirect to Google.com

This is my code:

```
    <div id="testTrigger"> Test Div </div>
    <a id ="TestButton" href="https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi5lY3N9Z3hAhUD9YMKHRjPCJcQPAgH" role="button">Test Button</a>

    <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $( "#testTrigger" ).click(function() {
          $("#TestButton").click();
        });
    });
    </script>
```

I tried all the ways I can think of, but nothing works.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `[0]` to the click trigger.

```js
 $( document ).ready(function() {
   $( "#testTrigger" ).click(function() {
     $('#TestButton').get(0).click();
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
 <div id="testTrigger"> Test Div </div>
 <a id ="TestButton" href="https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi5lY3N9Z3hAhUD9YMKHRjPCJcQPAgH" role="button">Test Button</a>
```